# interpret a string made of 0 and 1 as a binary sequence?

Tags: python

Using `python`, I want to convert/interpret a string made of 0 and 1 as if it was binary.

Assume I have a string that looks like this:

```
>>>str = "010010000110010101101100011011000110111100100000010101110110111101110010011011000110010000100001"
```

I would like a function (or whatever) to retrieve `Hello World!`.

Comment: @CoryKramer, isn't that the wrong dupe? OP wants it converted to ASCII, which is what the dupe I linked does.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. You're missing the connection between interpreting as binary and "retrieving "Hello World!".

Comment: @MorganThrapp We should let OP clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want.  `for i in xrange(0, len(b), 8)` gets the bits for each character separately, and `chr(int(b[i:i+8], 2))` converts the ASCII 1s and 0s to the character code.

```
>>> b = "010010000110010101101100011011000110111100100000010101110110111101110010011011000110010000100001"
>>> print "".join(chr(int(b[i:i+8], 2)) for i in xrange(0, len(b), 8))
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import izip

str = "010010000110010101101100011011000110111100100000010101110110111101110010011011000110010000100001"
print ''.join(chr(int(''.join(b8), 2)) for b8 in izip(*[iter(str)]*8))
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```